# Is there a way to region block a nextjs app without disabling automatic static optimization?

Tags: next.js

I need to block users from certain countries based on IP in my nextjs app.

I'm currently doing this via the `x-vercel-ip-country` header inside a `getInitialProps` call in `_.app.js`

However, using getInitialProps in `_.app.js` opts the app out of Automatic Static Optimization.  Is there a better alternative method for region blocking?

Comment: Since you're using static generation - wouldn't this only block only one country at build? Normally, this is done at the hosting level.  https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/5304

Comment: Have you considered using [Next.js redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching)? It can match routes based on request headers.

Comment: SeanW - I definitely considered using Cloudflare, but the product calls for only blocking some pages, not the entire app.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

@juliomalves - that's a great Idea. I didn't know about that.  Will look into and I think it may work. Thanks!